# oldest free assembler targeting the 386 CPU

Tags: 80386, assembler

What is the oldest free-to-use and royalty-free assembler targeting the Intel 80386 CPU in 32-bit protected mode, which knows all the instructions and addressing modes, and doesn't have obvious bugs?

Some which I was able to find:

- MASM (5.00 released in 1987) and TASM (1.0 released in 1988) already support the 386, but they were not free in the 1980s and 1990s.
- [MASM32](https://www.masm32.com/download.htm) contains *ml.exe* version 6.14.8444, this is MASM written and released by Microsoft in 1999. The license terms for including and using *ml.exe* in MASM32 are unclear.
- GNU Binutils 2.9.5 (released in 1999-08) has the GNU as(1) assembler, which is free, and its code generation seems to be good enough.
- GNU Binutils 2.9.1 (released on 1998-05-01) has the GNU as(1) assembler, but it has some obvious bugs, for example it generates 2 extra NUL bytes after a `mov $0x100, %bx` instruction.
- GNU Binutils 2.7 (released on 1996-07-15) has the GNU as(1) assembler, apparently with no extra bugs compared to 2.9.1 in my test program. See [source code](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.7.tar.gz) and [Linux i386 binaries precompiled by me](https://github.com/pts/pts-binutils-2.7).
- GNU Binutils 2.6 (found [in Debian 1.1 Buzz](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/buzz/main/source/devel/), released on 1995-12-23) has the GNU as(1) assembler, but it seems to be very buy: it generates incorrect code for `xor %al, %al` and `inc %al` and hundreds of other instructions.

Is there anything earlier than 1996-07? (That's about 11 years after the 80386 CPU was made available.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that while MASM and TASM were not free, they were of course pirated a lot, so what would have been the incentive for someone to spend the effort and make a free version? The "as" assembler came from a completely different direction (and uses AT&T-inspired syntax instead of Intel syntax, which many found weird back then). Also, completeness as in "has all instructions and addressing modes" definitely wouldn't have been a priority.

Comment: @dirkt I remember I found *as* with its weird AT&T syntax (the guys who invented it have really earned the prize for the most convoluted syntax....) basically unusable.

Comment: @tofro I had the same reaction, but `as` is the way it is of course because it can serve as a backend to `cc`, so to adapt to a new ISA like i386, they just add opcodes and registers, and don't change the syntax. That's also why "completeness" is not a priority.

Comment: @dirkt of course *as* was useful as part of the toolchain. It was definitely not useful (at least to me) as a stand-alone assembler.

Comment: @dirkt: The *directives* are the same as on other targets (modulo differences in meaning for `.align` being `.p2align` vs. `.balign` and stuff like that).  But AT&T syntax is AT&T's fault: *they* invented a whole new syntax for x86 machine code that uses the same register names and some of the same mnemonics as Intel, but opposite operand-order, and reg names decorated with `%`, immediates with `$`, and a totally different addressing-mode syntax.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info  / [What was the original reason for the design of AT&T assembly syntax?](//stackoverflow.com/q/42244028)

Comment: It's possible for a compiler to target some flavour of Intel syntax, if they're careful to include a way to disambiguate cases like the symbol name for C vars like `int eax`.  e.g. NASM where `$eax` is the symbol name not the register.  (That's also possible in GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` using double quotes but GCC doesn't bother; only AT&T syntax is really robust. [Disambiguate labels from register names in the Intel syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57605964))

Comment: @PeterCordes The answer you linked clearly explains that it goes back to the PDP-11, and `cc` was written for the PDP-11, and if you ever used `cc -S` (which still works today) then you also see **why** all other ISAs stuck to the same syntax. So it's not "AT&T's fault, they had to come up with something different", it was **made** this way to simplify porting `cc`/`as` for other CPUs.

Comment: @dirkt: GNU assembler uses standard ARM syntax on ARM, destination on the left, etc.  AT&T *could* have used some flavour of Intel syntax for their compiler and assembler; parsing PDP-11 vs. x86 instructions has to be a lot different anyway.  The pain that some people feel when having to use AT&T syntax can be blamed on AT&T. Especially the x87 syntax bug of swapping `fsub` with `fsubr` and similar mnemonics with reg operands! (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dBugs.html)

Comment: Maybe generating asm output from the compiler was slightly easier with a destination-on-the-right syntax, but short-term gain, long term pain.  (Except for people who *like* AT&T syntax. It does have its advantages, like clearer distinction between reg names vs. symbols, and clearer mapping of fields to machine code, less free-form in addressing modes.  I personally think NASM is very nice, but MASM is a disaster with how `[]` don't mean anything unless there's a register inside, not just constants / symbols, and multi-character literals are a total mess, although GAS is no better about that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, but ARM came way later than i386, and at that time extending the parser was less of an issue. Please don't try to rewrite history, I was there when it happened, and the reason really is "it was easier to take the existing toolchain and port it to i386 like this". I **have** used `as` with the AT&T syntax, and yes, it was painful, and at that time I also learned the reason for why they did it that way. "It's just AT&T being stupid" was not the reason.

Comment: gas had to have been available (however buggy) earlier than the late nineties as Linux was originally released in 1991.

Comment: gas added 386 support in 1989.  But that doesn't count because it had "obvious bugs" (which were so obvious they didn't impact gcc and weren't fixed for 10 years?) or something.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock: Generating 2 extra (harmful) NUL bytes after a  simple instruction is an obvious show-stopper bug for me when using an assembler. It's not an "obvious", but an obvious bug, very clearly. It didn't affect GCC because GCC never generated that instruction, because it was an instruction with a 16-bit immediate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The Netwide Assembler](https://www.nasm.us/) (NASM) was first released in October 1996. From the beginning it supported Intel syntax (similar to MASM and TASM) and most if not all known x86 instructions, and could be used to write protected-mode programs. It didn’t include an extender or linker of its own however, but third-party linkers and extenders were quickly made available (I used [ALINK](https://alink.sourceforge.net/) and [WDOSX](https://github.com/amindlost/wdosx)).

I remember this being quite a sensation at the time, since there were no free x86 assemblers with good coverage of the instruction set. Initial releases were buggy (mostly in corner-cases), so perhaps sometime in 1997 should be considered as the first mostly bug-free release.

Another early assembler with support for 32-bit segments and 386 instructions is Bruce Evans’ `as86`. The earliest version I can find [dates back to November 1991](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/bin/as86.src.tar.Z) and includes support for 386 instructions — in fact it’s [described](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/oldlinux/Linux.old/bin/as.doc.gz) as an updated assembler adding 386 support (to previous versions with 286 support). Later versions were released by [Robert de Bath](http://www.debath.co.uk/). As far as I’m aware this was never used much except to build portions of the Linux kernel and as a machine-code generator for `bcc` (Bruce Evans’ C compiler), so it might have bugs for patterns which don’t appear in those two scenarios. The project is available as [`dev86`](https://github.com/lkundrak/dev86) and is packaged in many Linux distributions (`bin86` in Debian and derivatives).

Comment: What I find interesting is strictly speaking you could use the netwide assembler without a linker if you had enough RAM (several times the size of the output binary). I've had only a little trouble getting NASM to spit out relocation tables.

Comment: That’s interesting, I used it without a linker to build .COM files but always used a linker for .EXEs.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** NASM 0.95 released on 1997-07-27  works for my test program, earlier NASM versions don't.

Here are some more details about early NASM versions (as suggested by **@Stephen Kitt**) downloaded from the [old NASM project on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nasm/files/nasm%20sources/):

- NASM 0.91 was released on 1996-11-22. It doesn't support `%macro`, `%define`, `%ifdef` or `%if`.
- NASM 0.92 was never released.
- NASM 0.93 was released on 1997-01-23.
- NASM 0.94 was released on 1997-04-08. New: it supports `%macro`, `%define` and `%ifdef`. Both the precompiled DOS version and the Linux version I compiled fail with *out of memory* for my test program (output `.bin` file smaller than 38 kB), so it looks like I've hit a bug. Simpler test programs do work.
- NASM 0.95 was released on 1997-07-27. New: it has `__NASM_MAJOR__` and `__NASM_MINOR__` macros predefined; it supports `-l listfile` output. This is the first version which works for my test program.
- NASM 0.96 was released on 1997-11-07. New: it supports `%if`, `align` and `alignb`.
- NASM 0.97 was released on 1997-12-06.

All the downloaded files were .zip archives containing C source and the *nasm.exe* program precompiled for DOS 8086. I've used the file time of each *nasm.exe* as the release date above.

The Makefile in each .zip archive contains working build instructions for GCC (for Linux etc.). The build is very simple: compile a bunch of `.c` files, and link them together.